# How to access field in list of JSON objects in a django SerializerMethodField?

Tags: json, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am creating an API for a game where users get points for labelling images. If a user has labeled an image with the same label as another, the score gets updated by 5 points (and 25 if that player is their opponent). I have declared the field score inside my serializer as a SerializerMethodField.

In the get_score method, I am trying to access the tag__name field inside the list of tags_to_compare and simply extract the strings and store them in a list.

I have tried the following inside my serializer:

**Update**
I have updated my get_score method as follows:

**serializers.py**

```
  score = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_score')

...

  def get_score(self, tagging):
    score = 0
    resource_id = tagging.resource.id
    # A previously played gameround for this resource is coordinated for Tag verification
    coordinated_gameround = Gameround.objects.all().filter(taggings__resource_id=resource_id).order_by("?").first()
    # list of tag_name from coordinated gameround
    coordinated_gameround_tags = coordinated_gameround.taggings.all().values_list("tag__name", flat=True)

    if Tag.objects.all().filter(name=tagging) in coordinated_gameround_tags:
      score += 25

return score
```

I tested the following line and it retrieves a list of taggings.

```
coordinated_gameround_tags = coordinated_gameround.taggings.all().values_list("tag__name", flat=True)
```

This is the JSON Object where the list of tags is:

```
{
    "gameround": {
        "id": 2014305513,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "carina",
            "is_superuser": true
        },
        "score": 50,
        "tags_to_compare": [
            {
                "tag_id": 153,
                "tag__name": "night",
                "tag__language": "en",
                "resource_id": 323570
            },
            {
                "tag_id": 10437,
                "tag__name": "dress",
                "tag__language": "en",
                "resource_id": 323570
            },
            {
                "tag_id": 9598,
                "tag__name": "sleep",
                "tag__language": "en",
                "resource_id": 323570
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`coordinated_gameround` is a `Gameround` instance of your model. Not a Dict. So you cannot access it with `coordinated_gameround[key]`.

If your `Gameround` has a field named "name" or "langage", you can get those values with

```
name = coordinated_gameround.name
langage = coordinated_gameround.langage
```

Also, there might be an error with this line

```py
Tag.objects.all().filter(name=tagging) in coordinated_gameround_tags
```

Do you expect `coordinated_gameround_tags` to contain a list of queryset ?

Comment: Is there a better way to somehow store the values ["night", "dress", "sleep"] in a list then?

Comment: You must be able to make 1 query that allows you to check if a user matches the criteria you have set. Checking the validity of this query (with `.exists()`) in your function would return the score without much effort. you would then juste have something like 
```
queryset = Tag.objects.filter(...)
return 25 if query.exists() else 0
```

Comment: Ok I think I solved by using ```coordinated_gameround_tags = coordinated_gameround.taggings.all().values_list("tag__name", flat=True) ```